# How to set an Image in background such that it will be see in other part of cardview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I am new in android app development.I am doing a project in android. I have set a image in background such that it will be see in other part of cardview.If anyone knows, please share your answer.My XML code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:src="@drawable/images1"/> 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RateMe"
            android:text="Rate your experience?"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Cleaniness"
            android:text="How was cleaniness?"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RateClean"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Comment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:hint="please enter comment here" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bttn"
            android:hint="Submit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your UI design ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jj6llVazLvRl9vblFLV3c2djQ/view

Comment: Background should be transparent

Comment: You want the activity background transparent ?

Comment: Yes I want to activity background transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to make your LinearLayout the color you want, and the cardView with a transparent background. With your code you should have something like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/bg">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#55FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RateMe"
            android:text="Rate your experience?"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Cleaniness"
            android:text="How was cleaniness?"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RateClean"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Comment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:hint="please enter comment here" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bttn"
            android:hint="Submit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: When I add a image in background it overlaps the card view.I want to UI such that part of image should be see in other part of cardview.

Comment: @Dipu Kumar I've edited the code to use a FrameLayout and changing the alpha of the CardView background. Maybe i don't get exactly what you want. If this code don't solve your problem, please add a comment with an exemple of what you want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your activity transparent then check this answer - [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)